# You are melting away

Tags: grammar

I've read a poem and there were such words:
'It seems like you are melting away in your dreams'.

Is it right construction? And can we say: 'you are melting away'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Melt away is an idiom and you can use it in a straight manner or metaphorically:

[Here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/melt+away)

> The sun melted the ice away.

Or

> The sun melted away the ice..

The idiom is used straightly whereas in your example:

> It seems like you are melting away in your dreams.

The idiom is used metaphorically.

Answer (score 0):

You can say a lot of things in poems and songs that don't make sense literally, but create an image in the reader's or listener's mind. It's very common for love poems to say things like, "I give you my heart." Of course the writer doesn't mean that he is offering the pumping organ in his chest for use in a transplant, but rather that he is expressing his love. Etc.

When something melts, it gets smaller and smaller and gradually disappears. So if a poet says, "You are melting away" ... I'd have to see the context, but I'd guess either, "my memory of you is slowing fading" -- perhaps this was someone he loved who has died or left him -- or "I feel like the relationship between us is becoming weaker and eventually we will break up". Or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

It is an idiom. Imagine being an ice cube that is thrown into hot water. That is the feeling that I think the author is using to convey. A surreal, floating sense of losing your grip on reality.